# return a new object from dictionary listing

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, types, polymorphism

I have a program where I'm using a Manager which maintains a dictionary of a generic class type.  I'd like to be able to register new types (using polymorphism) and store it in the dictionary (with an integer-based key), then be able to create new objects based upon that stored type.  Here is what I have:

```
Dictionary<uint,GenericClass> mGenericLibrary = new Dictionary<uint,GenericClass>();

public GenericClass GetNewGenericType(uint id)
{
     return mGenericLibrary[id];
}
```

The dictionary would be holding sub-classes of the GenericClass type, i.e. GenericClassSub1, GenericClassSub2, GenericClassSub3, etc....

At this point I'd like to in another class be able to call GetNewGenericType and get a new object which is of one of the sub types based upon the registered integer ID.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you just call `GetNewGenericType` from the other class? It is `public`.

Comment: would it not return the actual object inside the collection and not a new object?

Comment: So you want to return a new instance of the type for the object stored at a given `id`? If so, regardless of where it will be call, the `GetNewGenericType` is not doing that. You need to update the question specifying more clearly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called the "[Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)". Instead of the dictionary holding your types you want to create have the dictionary hold classes that genererate the types you want to create ("factories").

```
public abstract GenericFactory
{
    public abstract GenericClass CreateInstance();
}

public GenericClassSub1Factory : GenericFactory
{
    public override GenericClass CreateInstance()
    {
        return new GenericClassSub1();
    }
}

public GenericClassSub2Factory : GenericFactory
{
    public override BaseClass CreateInstance()
    {
        return new GenericClassSub2();
    }
}
```

You then declare your dictionary and use it like so:

```
class MyClassFactory
{
    Dictionary<uint,GenericFactory> mGenericLibrary = new Dictionary<uint,GenericFactory>();

    public void RegisterFactory(uint id, GenericFactory factory)
    {
        mGenericLibrary[id] = factory;
    }

    public GenericClass GetNewGenericType(uint id)
    {
         return mGenericLibrary[id].CreateInstance();
    }
}


void Example()
{
    var factory = new MyClassFactory();

    factory.RegisterFactory(1, new GenericClassSub1Factory());
    factory.RegisterFactory(2, new GenericClassSub2Factory());
    factory.RegisterFactory(3, new GenericClassSub3Factory());

    var item1 = factory.GetNewGenericType(1); //Contains a new GenericClassSub1;
    var item2 = factory.GetNewGenericType(2); //Contains a new GenericClassSub2;
    var item3 = factory.GetNewGenericType(3); //Contains a new GenericClassSub3;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

If you don't want to make people make the factory classes you could still do the factory pattern but do it via delegates, it would require a lot less code on the end user to add to the factory.

```
class MyClassFactory
{
    Dictionary<uint,Func<GenericClass>> mGenericLibrary = new Dictionary<uint,Func<GenericClass>>();

    public void RegisterFactory(uint id, Func<GenericClass> factory)
    {
        mGenericLibrary[id] = factory;
    }

    public GenericClass GetNewGenericType(uint id)
    {
         //This could be one line, but i think mGenericLibrary[id]() looks too weird.
         Func<GenericClass> factory = mGenericLibrary[id];
         return factory();
    }
}

    void Example()
{
    var factory = new MyClassFactory();

    factory.RegisterFactory(1, () => new GenericClassSub1());
    factory.RegisterFactory(2, () => new GenericClassSub2());
    factory.RegisterFactory(3, () => new GenericClassSub3());

    var item1 = factory.GetNewGenericType(1); //Contains a new GenericClassSub1;
    var item2 = factory.GetNewGenericType(2); //Contains a new GenericClassSub2;
    var item3 = factory.GetNewGenericType(3); //Contains a new GenericClassSub3;
}
```

Comment: I would use an `interface` but otherwise, not bad.

Comment: I would too, but he used `GenericClass` in his original code so I tried to match his schema. But yes, if you can replace the base class with a interface it will open up more options later down the line.

Comment: would it be possible in the base class to simply create a "CreateInstance()" method and use that?

what I'm really trying to do is make it so that the specific subobjects dont have to be known until runtime and whoever wants to add new subclasses doesnt have to make a factory along side the subclass when they want to extend, they just register the new type

Comment: You could, but that is kind of a odd pattern. Normally doing what you want to do is handled by a factory pattern, [The principal of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) states you should do what people expect to see. However I have a solution that may make you happy, updating answer.

Comment: @DavidTorrey Answer updated to use delegates so now the user does not need to explicitly create a factory class, he just needs to pass in a delegate that acts as a factory function.